# C opening and reading directories

Tags: c, linux, directory, ls

So im trying to write a program in C that works like the ls command from Linux,
for the moment i've been capable of listing the files and directories inside my Current working directory, but i don't seem to be capable of doing the same for directories that are not my CWD, do i need to change it before i start listing it? or does the function opendir() work for any directory?
It has to work like ls -li from Linux but i got the printing stuff handled.
In general my program looks like this (obvsly it has more things):

```
void function(char *directory_to_list){

DIR *d;
struct dirent *dirp;
struct stat filestat;

 if ( (d = opendir(directory_to_list)) == NULL){
    //print error
 }
 while ( ( dirp = readdir(d) ) != NULL){
    //here i call the stat() function for every entry to get various  information
    if (stat(dirp->d_name, &filestat) == -1){
       continue;
     }
    //various prints 
 }
 closedir(d);


}
```

EDIT: The command would be -> ls -li [-dir] so if you dont get any dir you just list your CWD.

EDIT2: No error is being returned it just does nothing, it opens the directory just fine but doenst list anything so i guess the stat call is not being done well, also added the line for how i call stat().

Comment: What do you mean by listing stuff not in your pwd? The goal of `ls -li` is to only list things in your pwd. Do you mean if you pass in a directory to list?

Comment: exactly, the command would be something like this: ls -li [-dir] so dir is option, which means if you dont pass any you list your CWD else you list the directoy you get passed, sorry for the bad explanation tho...

Comment: Can you show the output when you pass in an invalid directory for `[-dir]` flag? Is that what you are getting currently with valid directories? I am thinking that the issue may be if you are incorrectly using relative paths.

Comment: Right now it does nothing, no error, just it does nothing even if i pass a full path, and aparently it opens the directory just fine.

Comment: When the directory is not the current directory, you have to do something like concatenate the directory name and the file name from `readdir()` to create a name that you can `stat()`.  It's a standard problem; there are a number of similar questions — but, as ever, the problem will be identifying the duplicate.

Comment: Can you go a bit deeper on that? i mean i've been searching for an answer the whole day, reading and reading and never seen something like that, all the examples / questions i've come up with are for CWD ls.

Comment: What error is returned?

Comment: Print out `dir->d_name`. You will see it is just a base file name and not the full path to the file. You need to prefix `d_name` with the full path or a relative path reachable from the CWD and pass that to `stat`.

Comment: So i should be using something like realpath() for that? also, what do you mean with "reachable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version. Pay special attention that you do not overflow the buffer. you'll have to do some significant error checking to make this secure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int function(char *);

int main(void)
{
    function("/tmp");
    return 0;
}


int function(char *path)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *dentry;
    struct stat filestat;
    char *giantbuffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * ((PATH_MAX * 2 ) + 1) );

    if ( ( dir = opendir(path) ) )
    {
         dentry = readdir(dir);
         while ( dentry )
         {

              sprintf(giantbuffer, "%s/%s", path, dentry->d_name);
              printf("%s  ", giantbuffer);

              if (stat(giantbuffer, &filestat) == 0)
                  printf("%zu\n", filestat.st_size);

              dentry = readdir(dir);
         }
         closedir(dir);
    }
    else
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, instead of allocating the giantbuffer with PATH_MAX at the begining i called strlen() on path and dentry->d_name and added the + 2 (for the "/" and the "\0") and it works just fine, also, could you explain why this needs to be done? i dont seem to understand why i need to build the fullpath before calling stat when im not in the CWD.

Comment: Stat requires a full resolvable path in oder to find the file in question. Simply retrieving the names of a given directory is insufficient to supply this. Primarily opendir/readdir are used in a recursive loop in order to implement directory hierarchy traversal,. During this process the algorithm is actually rather "dumb" and explores the filesystem recursively by essentially "taking every left turn" until the entire labyrinth has been explored. This is essentially always built on top of the original path the user supplied no matter how sophisticated it eventually becomes.

Comment: Throughout all of this the C programmer must maintain the full path name by hand (generally so stat can be called on the file(but it could be for any number of functions or utilities ie; recursive cp copying)). Either by predicting buffer sizes via system limits or by measuring them first and realloc()ing memory like you suggested. Both have drawbacks and the latter has a time loss coefficient as well.